# Change the Launchpad logo on Ask Ubuntu's Contact and Login pages

Tags: support, status-review, design, launchpad

As of now, this is the logo of Launchpad shown in [Ask Ubuntu contact pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xewPi.png) (https://askubuntu.com/contact and https://meta.askubuntu.com/contact) and [login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ssX1.png) (https://askubuntu.com/users/login):

[image]

Recently, the logo of Launchpad was changed. This is the new logo: [image]

I request staff to change the logo in Ask Ubuntu contact page and login page. (This link might be helpful: https://launchpad.net/@@/launchpad-logo.png)

Comment: I am always ready to be corrected but I believe that AU mods can't actually make that change?

Comment: @andrew.46 Yup, mods can't make that change. That's why I mentioned "staff" in the post. Mods can help by adding [meta-tag:status-review] tag :) Per MSE: [What posts should be escalated to staff using \[status-review\], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642)

Comment: So you are looking at this (from 'New Questions): "Is the question only fully answerable by an employee?" ? I have added the status-review tag after a quick consult on the Teacher's Lounge...

Comment: @andrew.46 Yup. Precedent: https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/19699/revisions

Comment: It is updated in the main site, but not updated in the Meta... idk why.